# Getting the terms containing rational exponents to zero in an expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have some expressions. For example:

```
 expr=f[x]^(7/3) + 2*f[x]^(2 + 2/(3*n)) + f[x]
```

where n is an integer.

I want to get the terms containing rational exponents to zero. For the example above;  I want to reach `f[x]`.

My try is

```
expr /. f[x]^Rational[_, _] -> 0
```

or

```
Assuming[expr /. f[x]^Rational[_, _] -> 0, n \[Element] Integers]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PossibleIntegerQ[a_, n] := 
  Resolve[Exists[n, Element[n, Integers], Element[a, Integers]]]

expr /. f[x]^a_. /; ! PossibleIntegerQ[a, n] -> 0
(*    f[x]    *)
```

The combination of [`Resolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Resolve.html) and [`Exists`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exists.html) determines for each term $f(x)^a$ whether there exists an integer $n$ that makes the exponent $a(n)$ integer-valued (i.e., whether or not $a$ is "possibly an integer"). If not, the term is set to zero.

Answer (score 3):

[`Rational`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rational.html) numbers are atomic (i.e., cannot be divided into subexpressions)

```
AtomQ[3/4]

(* True *)
```

Consequently, rationals have no parts (although [`Numerator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Numerator.html) and [`Denominator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Denominator.html) act as if rationals had parts), and the pattern `Rational[_, _]` never occurs

```
expr = f[x]^(7/3) + 2*f[x]^(2 + 2/(3*n)) + f[x];

expr /. f[x]^(_?(! FreeQ[#, Rational] &)) :> 0

(* f[x] *)
```